# Allow access only from mobile and tablet devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, modernizr

My client has very specific request. He wants to block all "classic" computers (desktop/notebook).

So if I access the website from iPhone, Android or tablet it displays everything (the different resolutions I can hadle via responsive design). But when somebody from Mac or Windows or Linux (I know that Android is also based on gnu/linux ;) ) access the web, he gets only a message that "this web is only for mobile devices"or something like taht.

But I am not sure how to "ban" mac os, win, linux etc.

Could javascript(jQuery) library e.g. Modernizr or other do such specific condition "just mobile devices"?

What about Windows 8 :(  ?

i am really thankful for any advice, because I have never had such request before?

Comment: Well javascript can just be turned off, then I can get on it on my desktop. You'll need to use something server side

Comment: Any suggestion, so I can tell the client what need to be done on the server side, so, his expectations can be meet?

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at something like this: http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/wiki/Mobile_Detect It's PHP (server side code) that detects what the user is using to browse your site. You could do something like `if($detect->isTablet()){
    // Your code here.
} else { // redirect them }`

Comment: Thanks Andy, Bookmarked your link too. the script looks awesome too. I will test both scripts through the development of that website and potentially return back and give some feedback in my question or comment here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do this in several ways.

Either you check via javascript, but then you if somebody would turn off javascript you would be screwed again because they could take a look at the website:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // some code..
}
```

or you could check it via modernizr, but I don't know exactly how to do it in modernizr and you would also have the problem of turned off javascript code,

or you could download a script that is suitable for your case via:

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

another thing you could do is checking the screen resolution but, then we are back at the javascript case.

Comment: Wow, thanks for http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ . I have checked the PHP version and I don't know yet if it works, bt if yes, it would be the solution for my problem.

Comment: You are welcome, but in your case I would talk to the client, why it would be so much trouble to display the website via a browser. If it was useful, please make sure to accept the answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), Windows adds `Tablet PC` to the browser user agent if it is a tablet.

I suggest not doing this via javascript, because as states above: if javascript is disabled, people will be able to visit your site.